# Importing .class File Into Eclipse Project

Tags: java, eclipse, import

I have a single *compiled* .class file called "Searcher" that I downloaded from my computer, and now I would like to import it into an Eclipse project.  Here is what I have done so far.

1) Saved the .class file in an empty folder on my desktop

2) Created an empty eclipse project, right clicked the project and selected properties.

3) In the properties window I selected build path and clicked *add external class folder*

4) I added the folder with my .class file inside to the build path under "libraries"

5) In src I created a class with a main method.  I tried to instantiate the searcher class by entering

```
Searcher s = new Searcher();
```

6) When I hovered over the error message, I was told to "import Searcher", so the program obviously recognized the class.

7) After clicking import, an import declaration appeared at the top of my class,

"import searcher.Search;"

8) Search is the name of the folder, and searcher is the name of my class. Unfortunately, with that import declaration, I am still getting an error before I run the program.

In short, what do I need to do to use the functionality of the searcher class, and other classes In the future?  What should I do to fix my way of importing this class into Eclipse?  Thank you.

Comment: use http://java-decompiler.github.io/ to decompiler

Comment: Is `searcher` the *full* name of your class? There's no package declared for it?